# Transform df columns into separate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df like this:

| sending_currency | date | EUR | USD | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ARS | 2021-01-01 | 1.23 | 4.56 | ... |

And I would like to transform it into:

| date | currencies | exchange_rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | ARS->EUR | 1.23 |
| 2021-01-01 | ARS->USD | 4.56 |

I've tried pivot_table, but it doesn't seem to work. I would really appreciate every suggestion!

Comment: You are looking for [pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html). But is it a good decision for later analyses to combine sending and receiving currencies into one column? I would keep both currency names in separate columns to avoid that you have to search for substrings later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can use `pd.melt()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"sending_currency": ["ARS", "ARS", "JPY"],
                   "dates": [0, 7, 7], 
                   "EUR": [1.31, 3.21, 11.3], 
                   "USD": [4.7, 2.6, 8.6],
                   "JPY": [23.11, 17.2, None]})

df_new = df.melt(id_vars=df.columns[:2], value_vars=df.columns[2:], 
                 var_name="currencies", value_name="exchange_rate")
```

Output so far:

```
  sending_currency  dates currencies  exchange_rate
0              ARS      0        EUR           1.31
1              ARS      7        EUR           3.21
2              JPY      7        EUR          11.30
3              ARS      0        USD           4.70
4              ARS      7        USD           2.60
5              JPY      7        USD           8.60
6              ARS      0        JPY          23.11
7              ARS      7        JPY          17.20
8              JPY      7        JPY            NaN
```

You can combine the two columns containing the currency names but I would refrain from this and keep them separately.

```
df_new["currencies"] = df_new["sending_currency"] + ">" + df_new["currencies"]
df_new.pop("sending_currency")
```

Final output:

```
   dates currencies  exchange_rate
0      0    ARS>EUR           1.31
1      7    ARS>EUR           3.21
2      7    JPY>EUR          11.30
3      0    ARS>USD           4.70
4      7    ARS>USD           2.60
5      7    JPY>USD           8.60
6      0    ARS>JPY          23.11
7      7    ARS>JPY          17.20
8      7    JPY>JPY            NaN
```